# React-native Android : App stuck on splashscreen on resume

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

My app is stuck on splashscreen after resume:

- Launch app
- Press on back (go to Android dashboard)
- Click on app icon
- > app is stuck on splascreen

Here are my dependencies :

```
"react-native": "^0.57.4",
"react-native-code-push": "^5.4.2",
"react-native-collapsible": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
"react-native-fast-image": "^5.1.0",
"react-native-geocoder": "git://github.com/pizzahutuk/react-native-geocoder",
"react-native-google-analytics-bridge": "^6.1.2",
"react-native-google-autocomplete": "^0.1.5",
"react-native-image-picker": "^0.27.1",
"react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.0",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.4.2",
"react-native-maps": "git://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps.git#1844d46902629e2caa55527d5bff48a550d92525",
"react-native-picker-select": "^4.4.0",
"react-native-sensors": "^4.0.0",
"react-native-splash-screen": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-svg": "^8.0.8",
"react-native-video": "^3.2.1",
"react-navigation": "^2.16.0",
"react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.6",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router": "^4.3.1",
"redux": "^4.0.0"
```

Here is the log from adb logcat during the issue :

11-13 15:45:30.710  2290  2290 W ResourceType: No known package when getting name for resource number 0x9c020204
11-13 15:45:30.710  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher onclick begin com.huawei.android.launcher.BubbleTextView{d7d30af VFED..CL. ...P..ID 528,1280-792,1570 #9c020204}
11-13 15:45:30.710  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher.Utilities  startActivitySafely useLaunchAnimation = true
11-13 15:45:30.710  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher.Utilities  startActivitySafely begin startActivity() for current user
11-13 15:45:30.714  2239  2239 I K3V3CpuGovernorPolicy: set scene Hmp policy : 300 , 150
11-13 15:45:30.717  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher.Utilities  startActivitySafely end startActivity() for current user
11-13 15:45:30.717  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher this view's parent is not SearchGridView , so no need to reportRecentApp.
11-13 15:45:30.717  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher onclick end
11-13 15:45:30.719  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher onPause()
11-13 15:45:30.720  2290 12810 I HwLauncher: Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco begin,flg = 403
11-13 15:45:30.720  2290 12810 W HwLauncher: Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco service flg 403 is unavailable
11-13 15:45:30.725  2239  3057 W PGApi_client: recv actoionId = 10000, action = com.huawei.pgmng.PGAction@3b9ef2f actionId =10000 pkg =air.com.unit9.frapp extend1 =1390 extend2 = flag =3 type =1
11-13 15:45:30.726  2290 12809 I HwLauncher: Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco begin,flg = 402
11-13 15:45:30.726  2290 12809 W HwLauncher: Launcher.MotionManager stopMotionAppsReco service flg 402 is unavailable
11-13 15:45:30.729  1893  2018 I HwSystemManager: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10185
11-13 15:45:30.729 10855 10985 I HwSystemManager: NotificationGuideService:handle MSG_ACTIVIY_FOREGROUND, uid:10185
11-13 15:45:30.730  2290  2290 I SendBroadcastPermission: action:com.huawei.android.action.WIDGET_FOCUS_CHANGE, mPermissionType:0
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: air.com.unit9.frapp
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:321)
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at com.huawei.systemmanager.netassistant.netapp.service.NetControllService.checkShowNetWorkToast(NetControllService.java:170)
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at com.huawei.systemmanager.netassistant.netapp.service.NetControllService.access$100(NetControllService.java:56)
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at com.huawei.systemmanager.netassistant.netapp.service.NetControllService$1.handleMessage(NetControllService.java:114)
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-13 15:45:30.732 10855 11018 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
11-13 15:45:30.733 10855 11018 W System.err:    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-13 15:45:30.737  1893  2093 I HwResources: load icon id : 7f0a0000, pkgName : air.com.unit9.frapp
11-13 15:45:30.744   388  1107 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0x933
11-13 15:45:30.744   388  1107 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a58400): interfmt=0x1, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.745  1893  2093 I HwResources: icon : air.com.unit9.frapp found in app
11-13 15:45:30.745 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: Running application "App" with appParams: {"rootTag":11}. **DEV** === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
11-13 15:45:30.770   388 12146 I gralloc : Free handle(0x7f68a42b00)
11-13 15:45:30.770   388 12146 I gralloc : Free handle(0x7f68a58300)
11-13 15:45:30.771   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.772   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a58600): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.772   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.781   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f83e88b00): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.781   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.782   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a58700): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.788   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.793   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a58800): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.793   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.798   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a58900): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.798   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc req: dev=0x7f83e42540, w=1080, h=1920, format=0x1, usage=0xb00
11-13 15:45:30.798   388   419 I gralloc : Alloc handle(0x7f68a42200): interfmt=0x200000001, stride=1088, size=8486912
11-13 15:45:30.819   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: running processNameair.com.unit9.frapp
11-13 15:45:30.819   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: HwCHRWifiUIDWebSpeed [appName=com.mobilesrepublic.appy UID=10104  WEBSENDSEGS=9  WEBRESENDSEGS=0  WEBRECVSEGS=12  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=0  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=12  WEBRTTSEGS=2  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.820   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: HwCHRWifiUIDWebSpeed [appName=com.google.uid.shared:10010 UID=10010  WEBSENDSEGS=18  WEBRESENDSEGS=0  WEBRECVSEGS=11  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=0  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=40  WEBRTTSEGS=9  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.820   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: HwCHRWifiUIDWebSpeed [appName=com.google.uid.shared:10010 UID=1010010  WEBSENDSEGS=0  WEBRESENDSEGS=0  WEBRECVSEGS=1  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=0  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=0  WEBRTTSEGS=0  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.820   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: HwCHRWifiUIDWebSpeed [appName=com.meraki.sm UID=1010109  WEBSENDSEGS=28  WEBRESENDSEGS=0  WEBRECVSEGS=24  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=0  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=15  WEBRTTSEGS=8  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.820   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: HwCHRWifiUIDWebSpeed [appName=air.com.unit9.frapp UID=10185  WEBSENDSEGS=40  WEBRESENDSEGS=0  WEBRECVSEGS=28  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=0  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=182  WEBRTTSEGS=17  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.820   961  1609 E HwCHRWebMonitor: WebMonitor [mNetWorkIsSuck=false mUIDIsSuck=]  WebSpeed [WEBSENDSEGS=132  WEBRESENDSEGS=8  WEBRECVSEGS=89  WEBERRSEGS=0  WEBOUTRSTS=5  WEBESTABLISRST=0  WEBRTTDURATION=253  WEBRTTSEGS=38  WEBSRTT=860  WEBSNDDUPACKS=0  SENDSEGS=0  RESENDSEGS=0  RECVSEGS=0  ERRSEGS=0  OUTRSTS=0  ESTABLISRST=0  RTTDURATION=0  RTTSEGS=0  SNDDUPACKS=0  suckTimes=0 recovage_times=0]
11-13 15:45:30.844   961  1084 I ActivityManager: Displayed air.com.unit9.frapp/.MainActivity: +124ms
11-13 15:45:30.898 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] Checking for update.
11-13 15:45:30.903 12692 12705 I art     : Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 45 MB
11-13 15:45:30.919 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: {"event":"gaevent","eventparameters":{"category":"TAB","action":"Accueil","label":"Page Accueil","value":0,"noninteraction":false}}
11-13 15:45:30.921 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] Reporting binary update (2.0)
11-13 15:45:30.962 12692 12705 I art     : Object allocation is busy now, so prior to grow the heap. New heap size is 54 MB
11-13 15:45:31.006  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher mUnlockScreenRunnbale  getOrientationEnabled false 
11-13 15:45:31.006  2290  2290 I HwLauncher: Launcher onStop()
11-13 15:45:31.025   961  1572 E WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=5200 BSSID=8a:15:14:74:7c:f2 RSSI=-39 "tiptopdev"WPA_PSK
11-13 15:45:31.027   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: spd good count:0, add sc:0.0, rate:1.0
11-13 15:45:31.027   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: current mHighDataFlowRate = 1.0
11-13 15:45:31.028   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: POta txb txg rxg:0, 58, 0. Lr =0% Totpkt=58
11-13 15:45:31.028   961   961 I WifiProJNI: ######### CMD_QUERY_PKTS ########
11-13 15:45:31.028   961  1616 I QosMonitor: postEventFromNative: msg=100,arg1=0,arg2=9
11-13 15:45:31.028   961  1616 W WifiProJNI: poll before: g_monitor_fd =175
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: PTcp RTT:860, rtt pkt=17, tcp_rx=30, tcp_tx=45, tcp_reTran=0, rtRate=0
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine:  pkt chk not bad, reset sc to 0.
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: net speed good
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: judge good link######, goodLinkLevel=3
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: sendResultMsgToQM bssid:8a:15:**:**:7c:f2, qoslevel=3
11-13 15:45:31.030   961  1618 I HuaweiWifiWatchdogStateMachine: link good reported, good base rssi:-39
11-13 15:45:31.035   388   388 I gralloc : Free handle(0x7f68a42e00)
11-13 15:45:31.051   388   388 I gralloc : Free handle(0x7f68a58400)
11-13 15:45:31.132 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] Report status failed: {"appVersion":"2.0"}
11-13 15:45:31.133 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] An unknown error occurred.
11-13 15:45:31.134 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: [CodePush] 400: An update check must include a valid deployment key - please check that your app has been configured correctly. To view available deployment keys, run 'code-push deployment ls  -k'.
11-13 15:45:31.333 12692 12738 I ReactNativeJS: {"event":"pageview","page":{"category":"Home","path":"","title":"tip top FRANCE"}}
11-13 15:45:31.428  2239  2239 I K3V3CpuGovernorPolicy: set scene Hmp policy : 665 , 256
11-13 15:45:31.968   961   961 I TrafficMonitor: update:rxPkts:9,txPkts:7,rxBytes:4525,txBytes:1574
11-13 15:45:31.968   961   961 I TrafficMonitor: start expired. level:-1
11-13 15:45:31.968   961   961 I TrafficMonitor: gettimer:interval=2000
11-13 15:45:32.338   961  1572 E WifiConfigStore: updateConfiguration freq=5200 BSSID=8a:15:14:74:7c:f2 RSSI=-38 "tiptopdev"WPA_PSK

Any idea?

Thanks !

Comment: Where is the code that hides the splash screen?

Comment: componentDidUpdate() {
        const { nav, dataLoaded, titial } = this.props
        if (dataLoaded) {
            if (!(titial && titial.titialAnimation)) {
                const routeTabs = routes.TABS
                const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                        NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: routeTabs })
                    ]
                })
                nav.dispatch(resetAction)
                nav.navigate(routeTabs)
            }
            SplashScreen.hide()
        }
    }

Comment: You should debug it and check if `SplashScreen.hide()` is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `SplashScreen.hide()` from the `componentDidMount()` function.

You can add a delay if you wish, for example:

```
import { InteractionManager } from 'react-native';

...

componentDidMount() {

  // Some code here if needed.

  InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      SplashScreen.hide();
    }, 750);
  });
}
```

If you have to call it from the `componentDidUpdate()` (because you need some data to be ready), just call it, not from inside an if statement. If the splash screen is already gone, `SplashScreen.hide()` will not do any harm.

(And remember this - The `componentDidUpdate()` is not calle after the first render, only after the second one)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I don't why but on Android my rootcomponent is not called in this case (iOS is ok).